# How do I create a percentage completion formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a project plan with different tasks, each with a reference number i.e. main step, key activity and task.  I have planned start date and planned end date for each in two separate columns.  I want to figure out how far behind or on track I am with my project dates using by creating a formula/if statement. Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: Where is your task progress information? Knowing the planned start and end dates is not enough to give you a meaningful estimate of how far ahead or behind you are.

Answer (score 1):

This is only an example that you can adapt to your needs.  The job involves placing 600 large blocks.  We initially assume that we can place 3 blocks per day.  The job started April 1st.  In *A2* we enter:

4/1/2015

In *B2* we enter the formula:

**=A2+600/3**   our initial estimate of the end date.In *C2* we enter today's date and in *D2* we enter the total progress to date.  (Both *C1* and *D1* can be updated daily.)
In *D3* we enter the formula:

**=D2/600**  This is our percent complete.
In *E2* we enter a formula to re-evaluate the productivity based on actual data:

**=D2/(C2-A2)**

Finally in *F2* we can enter our latest, best, estimate of the completion  date:

**=TODAY()+(600-D2)/E2**  Here is a sample:

[image]

In this sample, we initially thought it would take 200 days to place the blocks.  We now see that the actual productivity is only around **2.2** compared to **3.0**  This allows us to re-estimate the completion date based upon the actual productivity and the number of blocks that still must be placed.